# How to make a specific query on mapped objects with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

```
  menu              menu_autorization                authorization
----------        -----------------------        -----------------------
|id|title|        |id|menu|authorization|        |id|authorization|info|
----------        -----------------------        -----------------------
  |                     |        |                |
  |---------------------|        |----------------|
```

I mapped this DB with Hibernate; when I get a **Menu** object from the database I also get, correctly, **menu_autorization** and **authorization** objects.

For each **Menu** object I have many **menu_autorization** objects.

The query I wrote so far makes me get all the menu objects in the DB; what I want to do is to write a query that makes me get a **menu** object with a specific  **menu_autorization**.

How can I do it, since I don't have and **authorization** field in the table **menu**?
Maybe I can do it using Criteria, but I don't know how.

I have this mapping in Menu.class

```
...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="menu", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)  
        private Set<MenuAuthorization> menuAuthorization;
...
```

this mapping in MenuAuthorization.class

```
  ...

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity=Menu.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="menu",referencedColumnName="id")
    private Menu menu;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity=Authorizazion.class)  
    @JoinColumn(name="authorizazion",referencedColumnName="id")
    private Authorizazion authorizazion;
        ....
```

and this in Authorization.class

```
...
@OneToMany(mappedBy="Authorization", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<MenuAuthorization> MenuAuthorization;
...
```

Comment: How is the relation between `menu` and `menu_autorization` created in Java? Show us the relevant parts of your JPA entity classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with JPQL using something like this

```
select m from Menu m join m.menuAuthorization ma where ma.id = :maId
```

Using Criteria API you could do it like this

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Menu.class)
criteria.createAlias("menuAuthorization", "ma");
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("ma.id", maId));
Menu menu = (Menu)criteria.uniqueResult();
```